# Как не дать игрокам проходить сквозь стены? Unity 3D

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать, что бы игроки не могли проходить сквозь стены, и другие объекты в Unity (Steam Vr) через привязку объекта к игроку? Версия 2021.3.29f1. (Колайдеры есть)